# Rails 3.1 and RSS Reader

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rss, feed

I want to create a rails 3 app for Reading Rss(Feed). but i could not to find good way in rails 3.

this code is working. but i want to read full content of rss. that does not support.

```
require 'rss/2.0'
require 'open-uri'

result = RSS::Parser.parse(response, false)
output += "Feed Title: #{result.channel.title}<br />"
```

Comment: Does the source provide full feeds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FeedZirra](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra) is a good gem for this sort of thing. Simply do this:

```
require 'feedzirra'

feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse("http://feeds.feedburner.com/PaulDixExplainsNothing")
puts feed.entries.first.title
puts feed.entries.first.content
```

Comment: but I could not use feedzirra gem in rails 3

Comment: FeedZirra is a generic library, it doesn't have to integrate with Rails in any way. Just include it in your Gemfile, bundle install, and you'll have access to it just about anywhere in your code.

Comment: Yeah, currently working with feedzirra in rails 4 and works great

Comment: Nowadays renamed to Feedjira.